# Xcode 8.1 (and 8.2 beta) don't update code in assistant view

Tags: ios, swift

I find that the assistant view editor doesn't work properly at all. When I drag a connection from a label or button to the code file, it does not show up in the code until I close the assistant editor and open the code file by itself. If I'm hooking up multiple items, this gets frustrating because sometimes the second button will connect inside the brackets of the previous one and give me an error.

[image: Sample]

Am I the only one this is happening to? Am I doing something wrong? Also in the assistant editor view, I'm getting "error type" which doesn't show up in the standard editor. Ideas?

[image: Sample]

Comment: How are you adding a @IBAction inside another one? That doesn't work

Comment: That's what I'm saying. When I use the assistant view, I'll add the first @IBAction, and it doesn't update the .swift file, so it looks like nothing changed. Then I'll add the second one, and when I go back to the standard editor, it's done that for me automatically and I have to delete the connection and go back.

Answer (score 1):

First check if there is a mismatch between your class name and the name registered in the ID tab of the View Controller. Then try:

- Clean your proect
- Delete Derived Data
- Force Quit Xcode.
- Re-Open Xcode, Clean project. Run project.

Please tell me if this works or does not so I can help you further!

Comment: Tried them all, hoped it would work, still the same problem. The Assistant editor just refuses to update at all unless I switch back to the standard editor.

Comment: There is potential the there is a discrepency between your View Controller (the code) class and your View controller in the storyboard. Check that the storyboard is ciompletely connected to the file from the Utility Tab (Top-Right). If it is not, connect it. If it is, re-connect it.

Comment: Also, go to the View Controller class that is the problem, open up the Utility Tab, go to the File Inspactor (Looks like a paper), then make sure Target Membership is checked where it should be. This makes sure that the file is associated with yoiur active project scheme the way it should be.